# How do you unlock a domain object after calling lock()?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

If you call `lock()` on a domain instance or statically on the class, and then you decide there is nothing to do to the object, is there a way to manually and immediately release the lock?

Comment: It is locked for update, so you can call `save()` on the domain object to release the lock although it might be expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on what [dmahapatro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2051952/dmahapatro) said, the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/lock.html) indicate:

> The lock is automatically released when the transaction commits

so once you call `.save()`, the lock will be released when the transaction for that save commits (typically at end of service method).

You may also want to check out these [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#locking).

Comment: I had already seen the docs you refer to.  I was hoping that they had simply left something out, i.e. a way to reverse an unwanted lock.  I guess there's no other way, or you or the docs would have mentioned it?  What about a nested transaction?  Could I begin a nested transaction, lock a row, and then rollback the nested transaction if the lock was unnecessary?

Comment: @greymatter Hm, not sure about a nested transactions, but I did find this link that may be helpful? http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Service-transaction-and-locks-td1355167.html

Comment: It wasn't what I was hoping for, but I'm going to mark this answered.  Thanks!

Comment: There is a problem, of course ... e.g. an exception gets thrown so spring would automatically rollback ... but you capture it for X reasons. You may want to release the lock manually. Maybe a discard will release it?

Answer (score 0):

Lock is released when the transaction is committed but not when you just call save() because after save() transaction is still alive. Transaction may be committed when code execution leaves service method or when hibernate session is flushed (after http request is finished the session is flushed and cleared).

The best way to release a lock is using manual transaction handling. In service do this:

```
def saveUser(Long userId)
{
    User.withNewTransaction { TransactionStatus status ->
        User user = User.lock(userId)
        user.save()
    }
}
```

Comment: Service methods are automatically placed in transactions (by default).

Comment: Yes, but it happens too late, Another concurrent transaction cannot see it, service can call other services and it can takes minutes or so until transaction will be comitted.

Comment: I see, i didn't read your answer clearly. Thanks for elaborating.